# Running a simple rack app with SSL on localhost?

Tags: ruby, rack

I have a simple rack app that is serving up a static file. I need to use SSL locally for development purposes. Any way to do with with rack?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd just grab the `tunnels` gem, then fire up an SSL proxy using that:

```
sudo tunnels 443 9292
```